# After renewing Android Studio the reference to textView doesn't work

Tags: kotlin, textview

I tried to invalidate caches and restart and I tried to add kotlinx.android.synthetic.activity_main.* to import but it hasn't gave any changes.
I'm a newbie in programming so I suppose there must any easy solution)

Comment: Please share the code snippet of what you tried

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend exploring [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) for accessing your views instead. Android Synthetics are being deprecated soon anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've already started to explore it) I suppose they already have stopped to support it or something like that

Comment: It's really painful when you start to learn something and some of easiest things goes wrong)

Comment: View Binding didn't work as well. I went to Tools-Kotlin-Configure Kotlin Plugin Update and then unchecked the following items: script definition for extension scripts and IDE console and MainKTSScript. Now it works.

Comment: but also I had to put kotlin extensions in gradle, so anyway I need to migrate to viewBinding